# Website and email google apps redirects

Tags: email, dns, google-apps, cname, mx-record

I've set up MX records as such:

```
5     @    ALT1.ASPMX.L.GOOGLE.COM
5     @    ALT2.ASPMX.L.GOOGLE.COM
10    @    ALT3.ASPMX.L.GOOGLE.COM
10    @    ALT4.ASPMX.L.GOOGLE.COM
1     @    ASPMX.L.GOOGLE.COM
```

CNAME as such:

```
www    xxxx.rhcloud.com
```

The problem is that xxxx.com does not resolve to www.xxxx.com in a web browser.

The second problem is that emails sent to xxxx.com return with "DNS Error: Address resolution of xxxx.ca. failed: DNS server returned answer with no data". And before, "The recipient server did not accept our requests to connect.".

Another thing was [this](http://mxtoolbox.com/problem/smtp/SMTP-Reverse-DNS-Mismatch?page=health_smtp&hidetoc=0&hidepitch=1&showlogin=1&action=smtp:aspmx.l.google.com&domain=lethbridgefringe.ca). Not sure what that is.

I've seen some hints on the internet to set up an A record to route @ to the IP of the server, but rhcloud dosen't have one IP, I don't think.

I'm completely out of my depth here. I just want my google apps emails to work, and website to direct trafic to my rhcloud server.

Comment: Now emails sent directly to xxxx.com addresses get delivered, but forwarded emails from an old address return the "DNS server returned answer with no data" message. Accessing xxxx.com still gets nothing.

Answer (score 0):

You can't set your root domain as CNAME, only subdomain can be CNAME.
Root domain **must** have A-record if you want correct redirect to www.yoursite.com in web browser.

> I've seen some hints on the internet to set up an A record to route @ to the IP of the server, but rhcloud dosen't have one IP, I don't think.

Symbol "@" in DNS zone means "root domain without subdomains, so this two record are equal:

```
NAME                    TYPE   VALUE
--------------------------------------------------
someexample.com.        A      55.33.11.22
@                       A      55.33.11.22
```

I don't know how openshift works, but looks like you can have only subdomain directed to your xxx.openshift.com application.

Issues with MX records in is unrelated to first question and I can't say what actually wrong.
Will be better if you show your real domain name so I can look on real zone configuration.

Comment: I can't check MX record if you not show your xxxx.com domain.

Yes wwwizer.com/naked-domain-redirect can do exactly what you need.